# Is BeanPostProcessor postProcessAfterInitialization needed only to work with proxy?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-bean, spring-context

> A bean implementing BeanPostProcessor is called when all bean
> definitions will have been loaded, but no beans will have been
> instantiated yet
>
> BeanPostprocessor is executed after the bean object is created, as it
> can be executed before init() and after init().

Is `BeanPostProcessor` `postProcessAfterInitialization` needed only to work with proxy?

**UPD:** what we need 2 methods `postProcessBeforeInitialization` & `postProcessAfterInitialization` for? Why not just one `postProcessInitialization` ?

Comment: I don't understand your quesiton, please elaborate and make it more clear.

Comment: what we need 2 methods postProcessBeforeInitialization & postProcessAfterInitialization for? Why not just one?

Comment: The `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` only has a single method. You are probably confusing the `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` and the `BeanPostProcessor`. IMHO the question is answered in the [javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/BeanPostProcessor.html) of the last class (both the classlevel and method level).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Nullable
default Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean,
                                                        String beanName)
                                                 throws BeansException
```

Apply this BeanPostProcessor to the given new bean instance after any bean initialization callbacks (like InitializingBean's afterPropertiesSet or a custom init-method). The bean will already be populated with property values. The returned bean instance may be a wrapper around the original.